# Confusion with Python set()

Tags: python, python-3.x

I found this code to generate prime number in Python3:

```
def gen_primes(N):
    """Generate primes up to N"""
    primes = set()
    for n in range(2, N):
        if all(n % p > 0 for p in primes):
            primes.add(n)
            yield n
```

Here I have confusion with the line `if all(n % p > 0 for p in primes)`. Since `primes` is initially blank, so the code inside "if" should never execute.

To become confident, I tried the code below and it is not executing the code inside the "for".

```
primes = set()
n=2
print("---------Outside For Loop--------")
for p in primes:
    print("---------Inside For Loop------")
    if all(n%p>0):
        print("Hello")
    else:
        print("No Way")
```

So I need expert help here to understand how this prime number generator working in this case?

Comment: Look at the docs of function all when it gets empty list...

Comment: `all([])` returns `True`.

Comment: you can use ```help(all)``` to see the information

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your test doesn’t demonstrate the issue because the function all is what you should inspect:

```
all([])
>>>True
```

By default all return Trie for empty lists, because unless `all()` finds a false In a list it returns true.

Answer (score 1):

the `all()` function returns `True` if all items in an iterable are `True`, otherwise it returns `False`. If the iterable object is empty, the `all()` function also returns `True`.

I rewrote your function by replacing `all()` with `v` (which means validity) if the number is not prime (in other words it is not divisible by any number less than the number itself) `v = 0` and is not included in the `primes` set.

```
def gen_primes(N):
primes = set()

for n in range(2,N+1):

    v = 1

    for nn in range(2,n):
        if(n%nn == 0):
            v = 0
            break
    
    if v: primes.add(n)

return primes

print(gen_primes(23))
```